# In Scala is it possible to return more than one regex criteria from a string?

Tags: scala

Sorry couldn't think of a better title. I'm new to Scala and I'm trying to parse out variables out of "{}". I want to be able to write regex that returns all variables out of he handle bars like example below. In some cases the sql string would have one "{}" in others it might have multiple.

```
val sql_str = "select * from {tbl} a left join {tbl2} b on a.id = b.id "

val r = """.*\{(.*)\}.*""".r

val result = sql_str match {
  case r(value) => value
  case _ => ""
}
```

For instance if I had the follow string:

```
select * from {tbl}
```

the result should be: tbl

for

```
select * from {tbl} a left join {tbl2} b on a.id = b.id
```

the result should be: tbl, tbl2

I tried searching for solution but couldn't find one. Thanks for any pointers you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"""\{(.+?)}""".r
  .findAllMatchIn(sql)
  .map(_.group(1))
  .foreach(println)
```

Or a bit less efficient, but, perhaps, somewhat simpler:

```
   """\{.+?}""".r
   .findAllIn(sql)
   .map(_.tail.init)
   .foreach(println)
```

This assumes, you don't have nested or unbalanced braces, and will not work very well on something like `"foo {bar {bam} baz} {zap}}"`.
If you want to handle those cases, regex is probably not the right tool, you'd be better off with a simple recursive function traversing the string while keeping track of the braces.

Comment: Thank you. I do want to extract all matches so second option works well. Just curious why is it less efficient?

Comment: @codeBarer both options do the same thing (extract all matches). The second one is less efficient, because it does additional string manipulation (`_.tail.init`) after applying the regex.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. I don't think it's the greatest answer. If someone has an efficient way please share.

```
var sql_str = "select * from {tbl} a left join {tbl2} b on a.id = b.id"
var words = sql_str.split("\\s+")

var params = Array[String]()
val pattern = """.*\{(.*)\}.*""".r

words foreach(x=> if ((x match {case pattern(value)=> value case _=> ""})!="")  params=params:+x )

params foreach(x=> print(x))
```